# type signature of uncurry function

Tags: haskell

```
uncurry f=\(a,b)->f a b
```

`uncurry` converts a curried function to a function on pairs, but the function above just converts it to a curried function `f a b`. Doesn't that contradict the definition of the `uncurry` function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What pelotom and Chuck said is 100% right. I think you just got a little confused at some point about curry vs uncurry and function definitions.

---

We know that a curried function is one like:

`add x y = x + y`

It's definition would be:

`add :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a`

Add takes a `Num`, and returns a **function** that takes a `Num` and returns a `Num`.

By having it this way, we can get a **partially applied** function, like

`add3 = add 3`

Thanks to `add` being curried, when we can pass just one parameter (in this case, 3), we can get back a function that takes a `Num` and returns a `Num`.

```
>add3 5
8
```

Uncurried functions takes **tuples**, or grouped together values, like (1,2). (Note, tuples don't have to pairs. You can have a tuple of the form of (1,2,3,4,5). Just regular old uncurry deals with specifically pairs). If we changed our add to be uncurried, it'd be:

```
add :: (Num t) => (t, t) -> t
add (x, y) = x + y
```

Which takes a tuple of two `Num`s and returns a Num. We can't partially apply this like we did with add as a curried function. It needs **both** parameters, passed in a tuple.

Now, onto the uncurry function! (If you want to know the type of a function, use `:t <some function>` in GHCi, or use [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/)).

```
uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> ((a, b) -> c)
uncurry f=\(a,b)->f a b
```

So what do we know from this? It takes **f**, which we notice from the definition is a **curried** function from (a->b->c), and it returns a **uncurried function** ((a,b)->c).

If we feed uncurry our curried add (remember: `add x y`), what do we get back?

We get an **anonymous function**, or lambda function, that takes a tuple, and applies the values of the tuple, `a` and `b`, to our function, `add`.

`f a b` doesn't mean we get a function -- you'd see a `->` if that was the case. We just get the **value** of `f` with `a` and `b`.

It's kind of like if we did this by hand:

`tupleAdd (a,b) = add a b`

But `uncurry` does this all for us, and we can just continue along with our brand new uncurried form of our originally curried function.

Cool, hunh?

Answer (score 6):

Another  way of writing this definition so it's clearer what's going on would be:

```
uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c
uncurry f = \(a, b) -> (f a) b
```

The variable `f` has type `a -> b -> c`, i.e. it is a curried function, and `uncurry g` for some curried function `g` has the type `(a, b) -> c`, i.e. an uncurried function.

Remember that when `x` and `y` are terms, `x y` means *apply the function `x` to `y`*. And `f a b` (or `(f a) b`) means *apply the function `f` to the argument `a`, producing a function of type `b -> c`, then immediately apply this function to `b`, producing a result of type `c`*. So the right-hand side of this definition is just showing how to unpack the components of a tuple argument and apply them to a curried function, which is exactly the process of uncurrying!

Answer (score 5):

You can write a function which behaves the same way (and with the same signature) without a lambda:

```
uncurry' :: (a -> b -> c) -> ((a, b) -> c)
uncurry' f (a,b) = f a b
```

I think this version is easier to read. If you have a tupel and a function which takes two single values (or more exact, which takes one value and returns a function that takes the next value), the uncurry' function does the "unwrapping" of the tuple for us.

Generally if you see something like

```
f x y z = x + y + z
```

it's the same as

```
f = \x y z -> x + y + z
```

or

```
f x = \y -> (\z -> x + y + z)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're misreading. It does indeed return a function on pairs. That's what the `\(a,b)->` part means — it defines an anonymous function that takes a pair and performs the given function on the values in that pair.